# How to access external memory while device is connected with data cable in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I am trying to debug my app while connected to the system through USB data cable .
 my data are downloaded and should store in sd card specific memory , but i am not able to access sd card in this situation.

So any body help me how do i access external memory while connected to the data cable .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is option in device setting about mounting SD card. You could set it to "never" or to "promt".

Comment: But this is sign that your app is affected when user connects his device to computer with the same option.

Answer (score 2):

When usb-cable is connected, SD-card cannot be accessed. This is implemented on device operating system level. The only way to make sd-card accessible is detaching usb-cable connected to computer.